# Sublime Text 2 : Bottom/Top Bar instead of Side Bar

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I am using a portrait-oriented monitor to have a long sight of the codes. I want to set the sidebar located either at the top or at the bottom to free the space on the sidebar for the file opened. I looked up the settings but I can't find any solution. Is this possible?

Comment: It seems there is really no way how to change sidebar position in ST2. I personally also use portrait-oriented disaply but since the sidebar content often is more vertical than horizontal :) it isn't big deal for me. If necessary I use Ctrl+K,Ctrl+B to swiftly hide/show the sidebar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this in Sublime Text. You are better off just hiding/showing the sidebar when you need it and thne using `cmd + P` to toggle your open files.